# How to configure Arch Linux to set executable bits during Tycho build for Eclipse RCP

Tags: build, cross-platform, executable, tycho, archlinux

In relation to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067244/mac-distribution-of-eclipse-rcp-application-built-with-tycho-on-windows-doesnt) concerning cross-platform Tycho builds of an Eclipse RCP-based application, I have managed to get the build to produce the desired results (products including OS-specific executable launchers with the executable bits set) on a virtual machine running Xubuntu.

I have now switched from Xubuntu to Arch Linux running on a VirtualBox machine. The build works just fine, and the products are built as expected, but the executable bits aren't set anymore.

How can I configure ArchLinux for this to work correctly?

EDIT: Yes, I `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a bug similar to [Eclipse Bug #368089](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368089) for systems where the locale is not US English UTF-8. In my case it was `de_DE.UTF-8`.

To fix this, simply switch locale before the build as follows.

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Thanks to Jan Sievers and the great [Tycho User List](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/tycho-user) (an immensely helpful resource for everyone working with Tycho) for providing a quick solution.